# What does `~/ ` mean?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu. People keep using `~/filename` in their answers to my questions. What does `~/` mean?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`~/` is shorthand for the current user's home folder. So if your user name is "foobar" it expands to `/home/foobar/`

Comment: And if you want to refer to another `user` home directory you can use `~user`, as in `ls -l ~enzotib/Documents/`.

Comment: Actually, `~` is the shorthand for current user's home folder :)

Comment: @heartsmagic True, but `~/` is equally valid.

Comment: I did not say invalid :) Generally we see `~` instead of `~/`, since `/` is not necessary there.

Comment: This is only *usually* correct, but not *technically* correct. `~` actually expands to the value of the environment variable `HOME`. If you change the value of `HOME`, `~` will also no longer point to that user's home directory.

Comment: There's no place like ~

Comment: Tecnically `~` is what refers to the user's home folder.  The slash at the end is not required, and is just equivalent to adding the slash at the end of a directory path, and will have the same effect (ie, varies according to context).  That is, `~` is equivalent to `/home/user` and `~/` is equivalent to `/home/user/`.  The former concisely points to the directory, the latter can be used when using that directory as the root of some operation such as a destination for copying.

Comment: AND, 12 years later, this answer is still helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

An important thing is, if you are using the root user, `~/` will be the `/root` directory, not `/home/user_name`.

In this case, do:

```
> cd ~/ ; pwd ;
```

It will exit:

```
> /root
```

Comment: This is a direct result of the fact that `/root` is listed as the home directory of the root user in your `/etc/passwd` table.  It isn't a special case.

Answer (score 2):

In general the tilde ~ represents your home folder. Use it to refer to your home directory at the command line.