# What is the meaning of ~/ in ls -la ~/?

Tags: command-line, paths

I am new to Ubuntu. Please help me with the following question. what is the meaning of `~/` in `ls -la ~/`

Comment: See also: [What does ~/ mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85149/what-does-mean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "~/" is the current user's home directory
(usually /home/user for a normal user or /root for
the root user). The 'ls -la' part is a command named
'ls', which is used to list the contents of a directory,
with the switches '-l' '-a', that tell ls to show the
permissions of each file/directory (-l) and include hidden files and directories in the list (-a).

'ls -la ~/' basically means "list all the files and directories (including the hidden ones) in the current home directory and show their permissions".

Answer (score 1):

`~/` points to the current user home directory.

Same as `/home/user_name`