# cd ~/root doesn't work, is there way to enable it?

Tags: command-line, java, sudo, minecraft, jar

Is there a command where you can access root from the linux terminal? (`/cd ~root`)
I have had to change my minecraft saves files under root, and had to run the command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo java -jar Minecraft-Installer.jar
```

Running the jar file under "sudo" works, but it doesn't without it, for some reason.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: I think you might be confused about [what '~' means](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85149/what-does-mean).

Comment: What happens when you run Minecraft-Installer.jar without sudo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \`~/ \` mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85149/what-does-mean)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, a few things to note here:

- Why are your saves under root? Don't run Minecraft with sudo, and then it should be stored in your home directory.
- ~ is a shorthand for your home directory. The command `cd ~/root` does not make any sense.
- Your command should be formatted differently. Try running `cd ~/Downloads` and then `java -jar Minecraft-Installer.jar`.
- If you want to access the root user, run `su`.

Comment: `The command /cd ~root does not make any sense.` - no, `~user` means home of the given user. What doesn't make sense here is `/cd` - it should be just `cd ~root`.

Comment: ^^ yup, `~/root` would mean a directory called `root` *inside* the invoking user's `$HOME` whereas `~root` (without the `/`) means the *home directory of* the user with login name `root`, which makes sense and is `/root` by default (although its permissions likely prevent any user aside from `root` from `cd`ing to it).