# Can't find my folder | Meaning of ~

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, directory

I am new to ubuntu server and I cannot find this information online.

When I login via SSH I am in:

```
root@Ubunutu ~ #
```

I used `mkdir mydir` to create a folder, but I cannot find it anywhere (using filezilla).

I also do not understand what `~` means, where am I?

I can use `cd ..` then it will show `root@Ubunutu / #`, which I understand. From here I can use `ls` to see folders.

To summarize:

**What does `~` mean, which location is it?**

**Where is my folder?**

Comment: `~` means home directory of your user which is here `/root`, use `pwd` to see were you are. Your `mydir` should be here: `/root/mydir`.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/85149/what-does-mean and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998626/meaning-of-tilde-in-linux-bash-not-home-directory

Comment: Please don't use root. Your whole problem comes from THAT. Use the normal sudo method we all use for Ubuntu. Set up ssh with your normal user. Not with root. You will get into more and more trouble doing it like this: creating any file will also be created as root so when you log in as a normal user ... no permissions for your user